# Web SocketConfigurer - How to add controller

Tags: java, spring, websocket, controller

I'm new to web sockets so iv'e a few question. Since im using WebSocketConfigurer Interface with code implemented below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(this.socketHandler(), "/socket")
                .addInterceptors(new AuthInterceptor())
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler socketHandler() {
        return new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(socketHandler.class);
    }
}
```

1) Can i somehow add Controller that will listen to my /socket and execute commands when some1 sends message with destination /topic/user
something like:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @MessageMapping("/user")
    @SendTo("/topic/user")
    public String test() {
        //TODO: do something usefull
    }
}
```

Comment: The SendTo sends the return string to /topic/user whenever a websockets sends something to what you have in MessageMapping. If You want to initialize message being sent not as a response you need to autowire a messaging template:
 private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one more configuration

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   ....
}
```